# how do i write a python program to find if the input number is Armstrong number

Tags: python

```
def Counting(number):
count = 0
while(number > 0):
    number = number // 10
    count = count + 1
return count
number = int(input("Please Enter any number:"))
count = Counting(number)
```

i'm not sure what to do so i really can't do much

Comment: It looks like you have already written a program. Is there something wrong with this code? Does it give you the wrong answer? Does it throw an error? Please take the [tour], read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and ask a _specific_ question about your problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Program to test if a given number is an Armstrong number

```py
def is_armstrong(n):
    l = len(str(n))
    t = 0
    for d in str(n):
        t += int(d) ** l
    return t == n

print(is_armstrong(int(input('Enter a number: '))))
```

Output:

```html
Enter a number: 153
True
```

```html
Enter a number: 200
False
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 153  
s = n  
b = len(str(n))
summ = 0
while n != 0:
    r = n % 10
    summ = summ+(r**b)
    n = n//10
if s == summ:
    print("The given number", s, "is armstrong number")
else:
    print("The given number", s, "is not armstrong number")
```

Hope this helps. Thanks